# sync two folders on Windows 10 with real-time monitoring including file deletions

Tags: windows, linux, file-synchronization

Before anyone says this is a duplicate, I saw the multiple duplicate questions but they are all many years old and I'm hoping there are better solutions out now.

I have a Debian server that has my documents. I have multiple computers/laptops that I use. I want to keep synced, local copies of those documents. I can access the documents the server using SSH/SFTP or Samba, or other way really. Right now I just map the docs on the server as a Samba share.

There are numerous products that let you manually sync folders (like the network map and My Docuents) and they work but they are manual. I am hoping for something that runs as a service, with real-time sync.

And, I was hoping it could handle file deletions because many of the solutions I have seen cannot.

- if I add/delete a file locally, the client would automatically sync that to the server
- if a file is added/deleted on the server (either directly on the server or by way of another client) then the product would do a sync on some kind of regular interval (because otherwise the server would have to "notify" all the clients to do a sync and that seems resource exhaustive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a multi-way synch?

Something like DropBox - but, obviously, not DropBox itself, or you wouldn't be asking.

I would recommend that you look at BitTorrent Sync, which lets you set up your own local Torrent network, across multiple devices and will keep them in synch.

I am trapped behind a company firewall at the moment, so can’t quote form the actual web page, but you can find out a lot from [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resilio_Sync).

Oops, it has been renamed 

>   Resilio Sync (formerly BitTorrent Sync) by Resilio, Inc. is a proprietary peer-to-peer file synchronization tool available for Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, iOS, Windows Phone, Amazon Kindle Fire and BSD. It can sync files between devices on a local network, or between remote devices over the Internet via a modified version of the BitTorrent protocol.
>
>   Although not touted by the developers as an intended direct replacement nor competitor to cloud-based file synchronization services, it has attained much of its publicity in this potential role.[1] This is mainly due to the ability of Resilio Sync to address many of the concerns in existing services relating to file storage limits, privacy, cost, and performance

Another interesting read is [Should I Use BitTorrent Sync Instead of Dropbox?](https://lifehacker.com/should-i-use-bittorrent-sync-instead-of-dropbox-1522881147). It’s a few years old, but explains the principles involved quite well.

>   BitTorrent Sync uses peer-to-peer file sharing to synchronize your files between computers. When you point the BitTorrent Sync app at a directory on your computer, you share those files with any other computer that you give a secret passcode to. The data only lives on your computer and the computers you share it with (or mobile phones). It's never uploaded to a third party server like other file syncing programs. Since you data is never uploaded to a server, your storage capacity is only limited to your own hard drive, and no one else has access to your files.

---

Of course, there is always DropBox itself, which gives 2gB free. I personally prefer SpiderOak which is end to end encrypted so that even SpiderOak can’t read your files.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check BitTorrent Sync out. It looks promising.

Comment: Please come back and post what you found - it will help others in future

Comment: I checked out Resilio Sync (formerly BitTorrent Sync) and it is great but I picked Syncthings over it because it's open source. Both essentially do the same thing.

Comment: Thann feel free to post an answer and accpet it (you may have to wat before accepting). Doin so will help who read this questio others in future

Answer (score 1):

It's old but reliable, you can use it with Samba.
I myself have been using it for some years now.

Dimio's DSynchronize
http://dimio.altervista.org/eng/

Comment: Do you use it on Windows 10? I saw it and it looked very old/aged like it hadn't been updated in a while. I wasn't sure how well it would work on Windows 10...